# Implementation Strategies for Object Orientation

Tags: oop, object, implementation, smalltalk, squeak

I'm currently learning Smalltalk in the Squeak environment and I'm reading "Squeak - A Quick Trip To ObjectLand". I enter the object-oriented paradigm with some prior knowledge from Python and Java and this sentence from the book on page 36 has made me think:

> Smalltalk is a class-based implementation of an object-oriented language.

Short sentence but very interesting. In OO all terms like class, object, instance seem to be well-defined and seem to point to the one and only true meaning and you're likely to come across generic sentences like "objects are instances of a class".
But you hear seldom about implementation strategies. What does *implementation* of the object-oriented concept mean in this case? Are there implementations of OO languages other than classes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Javascript is a *prototype* based implementation of an OO language.

Instead of subclassing a class and creating an instance of that new class, you inherit behaviour by cloning a prototype.

As a historical note I should add that while Javascript is probably the most widely used prototype-using language, the first was David Ungar's and Randall Smith's [Self language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_%28programming_language%29).

There are several [implementations](http://russell-allen.com/squeak/prototypes/) of [prototypes](http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/units/UITS/prod/index.php?id=241&notitle=1) floating around for Squeak. I haven't used them, so I can't comment on the libraries.

Comment: Here is another prototype implementation for Smalltalk, http://scg.unibe.ch/staff/adriankuhn/protalk which actually bends the class point to point to the object it self. To my best knowledge, it is thus the only prototype framework for Smalltalk that provide *native* prototype for Smalltalk. All other implement prototypes as a layer on top of Smalltalks class based model.

Answer (score 5):

I never saw, but read about Emerald, that is object-oriented but neither class- nor prototype-based but seems to construct objects "one by one" with the help of a special constructor:

> However, Emerald objects do not require a Class object for their creation. In most object-based systems, the programmer first specifies a class object that defines the structure and behavior of all its instances. The class object also responds to new invocations to make new instances.
>
> In contrast, an Emerald object is created by executing an object constructor. An object constructor is an Emerald expression that defines the representation, the operations, and the process of an object.

See [Andrew Black, Norman Hutchinson, Eric Jul, and Henry Levy: "Object Structure in the Emerald System"](http://www.emeraldprogramminglanguage.org/OOPSLA-86-paper.pdf).