# How should super behave with instance-specific behavior?

Tags: smalltalk

Assume `object` is an instance of class `C`. Also assume that `object` has an instance-specific method `m` attached to it. The method `m` is defined in both `C` and its superclass `C0`. The question is, which method should the expression

```
super m
```

invoke when self == object, and why?

I see two possible answers:

1. C >> #m (the method in the object class)
2. C0 >> #m (the method in the object class superclass)

---

**EDIT**

Even though the way we implement instance-specific behavior shouldn't matter for the semantics of `super`, let me point out that my favorite implementation is the one that places the so called `MethodDictionaryArray` (or `MDA` for short) in object headers, instead of the object class. As you can imagine, a `MDA` contains the method dictionaries of the inheritance chain.

With this implementation you can put instance behavior in a new `MethodDictionary` (`MD`) and redefine the object's MDA as the nested array `#{MD. MDA}`.

Comment: Please clarify the inheritance chain. There are no actual "instance specific" methods in Smalltalk (at least not the ones I know) because behavior is always defined in a class. The way instance-specific methods work is that the object's class is changed to an anonymous subclass of its former class (we call that a "uniclass" in Squeak).

Comment: @BertFreudenberg please notice the **EDIT** I've added.

Comment: Leandro, I take it you've already read through the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14196417/983430)?

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter yes, I had read it a while ago. Do you think there is some hint there that would help with my question here?

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia Yeah, I think several of the links in the accepted answer might be helpful. I'm not too familiar with changing methods just on specific instances, so I can't offer an answer myself. But Hernan's answer to that question, even though more for VW, should help you get a test case set up to answer your own question.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO it should invoke `C0>>m` to behave just like 'normal' instances of `C`. The implementation detail of how the instance-specific behavior is realized shouldn't matter. If you copy a method from `C` to its instance, it should ideally behave exactly the same as before.

Answer (score 1):

The standard definition of super is that super sends a message to the same receiver as self but starts the method lookup in the class above the one where the current method is defined.

Comment: Right. But here the whole point is that the definition is not that easy to apply because the instance-specific method is not defined in any class.

Comment: I get it now.  I would then think of it as follows:  The normal search path for methods is a linear list.  With instance-specific behavior, a new method dictionary is added to the start of the list.  I would think, then, that super means to start searching in the next method dictionary in the list which would be for the class C.

Comment: Exactly. And you would also arrive at the same conclusion if you implement the specific behavior in a "lightweight" instance-specific class because such a class would be a subclass of the original one. But then, we would be deciding the semantics from the implementation and that's what I'm questioning.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that one can phrase the definition a bit differently,
to get at the proper resolution of the semantics.

If we consider the normal case to be equivalent to

```
'do not include in the search any methods that are defined
 by the receiver, include only those which are inherited'
```

then the implementation details are not required
 when we are
deciding which answer to expect.

Comment: Good point. And how this definition would respond my question?

Comment: Class C defines m, and the instance of c defines m. Both should be effectively 'skipped' by the super send, resulting in C0 >> #m (the method in the object class superclass)