# 'Unexpected token implements` error in Angular2

Tags: subclass, ecmascript-6, angular

**Sample:**

```js
@Pipe({ name: 'values',  pure: false })
export class ValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
    return Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key]);
  }
}
```

It appears that class inheritance is not supported in ES6. Is there an alternative that doesn't require reverse-engineering the super class?

Comment: Is compiling with typescript not an option?

Comment: @Langley This answer is marked with the `ecmascript-6` tag for a reason. If I intended to rewrite my whole app from scratch in TS, I wouldn't bother asking. Beside, NG2 is supposed to be ES6 friendly. Eventually other users will target ES6 and run into the same problem, so it's not exclusive to my implementation.

Comment: I am merely trying to get info about your scenario, tsconfig.ts has an ES6 option for the target, I wonder if that allows you to use ts without having to rewrite your whole app.

Comment: @Langley I'm using Traceur with decorators enabled. I'm not really looking to change or further complicate the transpile/build process. It works well as is. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: you can try and look at this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/a/34375152/3106920](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34375152/3106920)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 does have class inheritance. Classes are inherited by `extends`.

When you use `implements` you are asking for type checking against an interface. If you want type checking you should be using Typescript - if you don't need type checking then you don't need `implements`. Using implements doesn't have an effect on the output code — it's just for type checking during compile.

For example in typescript:

```
class myClass{
    public myID:number
    constructor(){
    }
     talk(){
         console.log("hi there");       
    }
}

class newClass {
    public myID:number;
    talk(){
        console.log("Hi from new Class");   
    }
}

class newClassImplements implements myClass {
    public myID:number;
    talk(){
        console.log("Hi from new Class");       
    }
}
```

`newClass` and `newClassImplements` both result in exactly the same javascript after compilation. The version with `implements` just asks the compiler to make sure it has the same interface as `myClass` if it doesn't you get an error at compilation.

In your sample above `ValuesPipe` isn't inheriting from `PipeTransform` it's simply implementing the interface. If you don't need the type checking you should be able to just write the function you want and forget about implementing the interface.

Comment: Derp. I probably should've figured that out sooner. Thanks.